# Merging mp4 files with Pathlib only

Tags: python

I just wanna know if this possible without using shutil to merge the files?
but by using pathlib only.

my old code for merging files:

```py
 def combine(source: str, output: str),
 
    with open(output, 'wb') as output_file:
        for file in iglob(os.path.join(source, "*.mp4")):
            print(f'Merging', file, end='\r')
            with open(file, 'rb') as input_file:
                shutil.copyfileobj(input_file, output_file)
```

This is what I tried with pathlib

```py
def combine(source: str, output: str),

    for file in Path(source).glob('*.mp4'):
        print(f'Merging', file)
        Path(output).write_bytes(file.read_bytes())
```

The problem is, it's not appending the bytes and combining to output file.

Comment: you can't merge with `Path`, nor `shutil` because it has to reconvert data in file - ie. skip headers from files and create only one header for all data. You would need rather `ffmpeg` to merge video files.

Comment: as I know `write_bytes` is only to create new file and it always remove previous content. You would have to read all data, join them in memory, and write all data to file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should only open the output file once and then write the bytes of each file you read.

```
def combine(source: str, output: str),
    print(f'Creating {output}')
    with open(Path(output), 'wb') as outfile:    

        for file in Path(source).glob('*.mp4'):
            print(f'Appending {file}')
            outfile.write(file.read_bytes())
```